# Does Azure Shared plan come with SQL Server and MySql?

Tags: azure

I'm looking at the Azure shared plan for $10 per month. Does it come with SQL Server and MySQL? I'm looking to host my personal site and project. I don't anything fancy. Just need the latest .Net support and if possible unlimited MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not the MS Azure marketing department.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) can be very difficult to figure out. So while this may not be a *programming* question, it sounds a lot like a *deployment* question that needs community help to answer.

[Azure websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/) don't come with any kind of database support built in, unless you're loading a website image from the gallery.

Generally, any kind of relational storage will cost money. But it just doesn't have to cost a lot of money. Microsoft now has "Basic" SQL Database instances ([in preview](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/#basic-standard-and-premium)) that could cost as little as $2.50 per month, with up to 2GB of space. For the time being they still have "Web" tier databases for $10 a month up to 1GB.

Also, nothing in Azure is "unlimited." You always have a nominal charge for storage and data transfers out of the datacenter. So even a "free" website will still cost a buck or two per month for infrastructure charges.

Note that if you have MSDN Premium or Ultimate, you get a $100 to $200 per month Azure credit.

Comment: Not completely accurate. Per the Websites page you linked to: *Relational Database: one 20MB Azure SQL Database and one 20MB MySQL database are available at the subscription level for the first twelve months of use; standard rates apply thereafter.* Not that it's a lot, but it's plenty to get started with. Further, per the [Data Transfer pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/) page, the first 5GB outbound traffic monthly is free (all inbound is free).

Comment: Yes, and even after 5GB outbound it's still pretty cheap. Is a 20MB database big enough?